# Creating simple function for subtraction in R

Tags: r

I am a beginner in working with functions in R.
I would like to help to construct a simple function with the following example below:

```
database 1
a  b 
1  70
3  74
4  76
6  68
```

I would like to create a new column in this dataset with the following condition:
column c: I want to generate values base on (threshold 73) 73 column b values - 73 = difference (70 - 73 first row) but if the value is negative I want to put 0.
Like this:

```
database 2
a  b  c
1  70 0
3  74 1
4  76 3 
6  68 0
```

please, does someone could show me any function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try `pmax`

```
df$c <- pmax(df$b-73,0)
```

or

```
df$c <- (df$b-73)*(df$b>73)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df$c <- ifelse(df$b-73<0,0,df$b-73)
```